# Create array from csv using readlines ruby

Tags: ruby

I can’t seem to get this to work

I know I can do this with csv gem but Im trying out new stuff and I want to do it this way. All Im trying to do is to read lines in from a csv and then create one array from each line. I then want to put the second element in each array.

So far I have

```
filed="/Users/me/Documents/Workbook3.csv"

if File.exists?(filed)
  File.readlines(filed).map {|d| puts d.split(",").to_a}
else puts "No file here”
```

The problem is that this creates one array which has all the lines in it whereas I want a separate array for each line (perhaps an array of arrays?)
Test data

```
Trade date,Settle date,Reference,Description,Unit cost (p),Quantity,Value (pounds)
04/09/2014,09/09/2014,S5411,Plus500 Ltd ILS0.01 152 @  419,419,152,624.93
02/09/2014,05/09/2014,B5406,Biomarin Pharmaceutical Com Stk USD0.001 150 @  4284.75,4284.75,150,-6439.08
29/08/2014,03/09/2014,S5398,Hargreaves Lansdown plc Ordinary 0.4p 520 @  1116.84,1116.84,520,5795.62
```

What I would like

```
S5411
B5406
S5398
```

Comment: try `puts d.split(',')[2]`

Comment: I still get the problem that its treated as one line so I just get one array. Perhaps readlines ignores newlines or something?

Comment: `readlines` is of course aware of newlines, that's the whole point ;-) Please show your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let write your data to a file:

```
s =<<THE_BITTER_END
Trade date,Settle date,Reference,Description,Unit cost (p),Quantity,Value (pounds)
04/09/2014,09/09/2014,S5411,Plus500 Ltd ILS0.01 152 @  419,419,152,624.93
02/09/2014,05/09/2014,B5406,Biomarin Pharmaceutical Com Stk USD0.001 150 @  4284.75,4284.75,150,-6439.08
29/08/2014,03/09/2014,S5398,Hargreaves Lansdown plc Ordinary 0.4p 520 @  1116.84,1116.84,520,5795.62
THE_BITTER_END

IO.write('temp',s)
  #=> 363
```

We can then do this:

```
arr = File.readlines('temp').map { |s| s.split(',') }
  #=> [["Trade date", "Settle date", "Reference", "Description", "Unit cost (p)",
        "Quantity", "Value (pounds)\n"],
       ["04/09/2014", "09/09/2014", "S5411",
        "Plus500 Ltd ILS0.01 152 @  419", "419", "152", "624.93\n"],
       ["02/09/2014", "05/09/2014", "B5406",
        "Biomarin Pharmaceutical Com Stk USD0.001 150 @  4284.75",
        "4284.75", "150", "-6439.08\n"],
       ["29/08/2014", "03/09/2014", "S5398",
        "Hargreaves Lansdown plc Ordinary 0.4p 520 @  1116.84", "1116.84",
        "520", "5795.62\n"]]
```

The values you want begin in the second element of `arr` and is the third element in each of those arrays. Therefore, you can pluck them out as follows:

```
arr[1..-1].map { |a| a[2] }
  #=> ["S5411", "B5406", "S5398"]
```

Adopting @Stefan's suggestion of putting `[2]` within the block containing `split`, we can write this more compactly as follows:

```
File.readlines('temp')[1..-1].map { |s| s.split(',')[2] }
  #=> ["S5411", "B5406", "S5398"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why you have to write it to a temporary file before reading it in

Comment: @SebastianZeki an example should be "self contained", i.e. it should include all the code and data that's needed to run it. See http://sscce.org

Comment: @Cary Why you have to write it to a temporary file before reading it in. Is it something to do with csv newlines?

Comment: Sebastian, I didn't have to. I could have assumed you read the file containing the string I called `s` in the heredoc.I did it for the reason @Stefan gave. It was only one extra line. It had nothing to do with CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use built-in class `CSV` to do this very easily.

```
require "csv"

s =<<THE_BITTER_END
Trade date,Settle date,Reference,Description,Unit cost (p),Quantity,Value (pounds)
04/09/2014,09/09/2014,S5411,Plus500 Ltd ILS0.01 152 @  419,419,152,624.93
02/09/2014,05/09/2014,B5406,Biomarin Pharmaceutical Com Stk USD0.001 150 @  4284.75,4284.75,150,-6439.08
29/08/2014,03/09/2014,S5398,Hargreaves Lansdown plc Ordinary 0.4p 520 @  1116.84,1116.84,520,5795.62
THE_BITTER_END

arr = CSV.parse(s, :headers=>true).collect { |row| row["Reference"] }
p arr
#=> ["S5411", "B5406", "S5398"]
```

PS: I have borrowed the string from @Cary's answer

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution especially given the fact that the OP stated a CSV file. This is a great example of an XY Problem and answer